# AVSpeechSynthesizer speaks not existing utterance iOS 10.0.2

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, nstimeinterval, avspeechsynthesizer

I am having an issue with `AVSpeechSynthesizer` with `iOS10.0.2`

My code works fine for `iOS7` to `iOS10` but this last update causes a problem with the utterance,

This is the code I've written

```
speechSynth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
speechSynth?.delegate = self

let textToSpeak = "21"

utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: textToSpeak)

let delay = 1

utterance?.preUtteranceDelay = NSTimeInterval(delay)

speechSynth!.speakUtterance(utterance!)
```

Now it works perfectly but `iOS10.0.2` doesn't handle the delay. When ran on devices with `iOS7` to 10 I get a 1 second delay before the spoken words like " 21" but on `iOS10.0.2`, instead of delay it says `"slnc1000 21"` and when I set the delay to 0.5 it says `"slnc500 21"` It doesn't seem to handle the delay and instead speaks it.

Anyways knows of a solution let me know.